# Laravel Tailwind CSS - generate all classes depends on ENV

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, vite

I just jump to laravel 9 recently (from few months ago), kinda wondering about,

1. Is it possible to generate all css classes (including custom classes), **BUT**, only when **APP_ENV** on **.env** is **not** production?
2. I tried to overcome No.1 (see below explanation), by using `const APP_ENV = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ENV;` on `tailwind.config.js` - so I can do `if - else` thing, to load things, but it produce an error - `offset is longer than source length! offset 81 > length 59`. Is it possible to get `.env` variables on `tailwind.config.js`?
3. As I tried to find another way for No.2. I'm narrowing my objective on No.1 and No.2, so, I tried to load all possibilities of my "custom classes" **only on dev**. By using [`safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) - to generate all my-own custom class, but it seems not working well, since, the custom class that I want to add doesn't added. I'm using this - `pattern: /./` - since I saw [this article](https://redpixelthemes.com/blog/tailwindcss-generate-all-classes/#using-safelist) says so (please, correct me if I'm wrong), but, it's indeed "hitting" all other classes, not just my custom classes. I want to add all of my "custom css class" without adding the variants one-by-one. Maybe something like `variants: *`? (I already check around on tailwind docs, but couldn't found something like that)

I tried a proper way, to just load all my custom classes like `pattern: /ctm/`, but as stated on tailwind documentation

> Patterns can only match against base utility names like /bg-red-.+/, and won’t match if the pattern includes a variant modifier like /hover:bg-red-.+/.

How can I do so, without me typing & guessing all of the possibility of variants?

---

Explanation how I try to overcome For question No.1 -

I tried using these code on `app.js`

```
const APP_ENV = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ENV;
if (APP_ENV == 'production') {
    //need to use ()
    import ('../css/app.css');
}
```

and with below code on app.blade.php

```
@if (config('app.env') != 'production')
            <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
        @endif
```

But, when it comes to a custom classes on `tailwind.config.js` - for example

```
theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },

            colors: {
                'ctm-dark-purple': '#2a234f', //<--- custom class here
                'ctm-light-dark-purple': '#2a234f', //<--- custom class here
            },
        },
    },
```

It doesn't generate that custom classes, since I "block" the generated class and swap it into `cdn` mode on dev.

---

So, in-summary, how can I "generate all css classes" only on "development" mode? **Along** with my "custom css class"? If that's not possible, then, is it possible to overcome No.3? I want to add all of my "custom css class" without adding the variants one-by-one. Maybe something like `variants: *`?

My main reason is simply, I want to apply classes directly on web-browser console and see the changes more faster, rather than back-and-forth modifying-then-save the code on text-editor.

Thanks a lot!

---

> Log -
> Updating Problem No.3 - since forgot to mention precisely what I want

Comment: You can try [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package - it will load env variables and within `tailwind.config.js` change content section with or w/o safelist pattern `/./` depends on environment

Comment: Hi @IharAliakseyenka- thanks for that suggestion! Totally forgot about that one! Seems that way can tackle issue No.1 & 2. Still wonder on how to tackle No.3.

Comment: As a I said - conditional [safelisting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) like `safelist: isProd ? [] : [{pattern: /./}]`, where `isProd` defined as production or not - something like `const isProd = process.env.APP_ENV === 'production'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @IharAliakseyenka ! Seems, I forgot to mention on problem No.3 at the first explanation.  What I meant before is more on Tailwind setting, about the "variants", if it's possible to do something like "variants: *", which, atm, I do add it one-by-one. (I'm gonna edit a bit my problem on No.3, sorry for misleading the question on No.3!)